# PHP, MySQL, React, Rest API tutorial confusion Part 2

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest

Still following the following tutorial:

https://www.techiediaries.com/php-react-rest-api-crud-tutorial/

I am finally getting no errors in the console.  But I am getting nothing but a blank array in the console that simply reads [ ]

The complete code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/babel">
  class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'api/testQuery.php'
    axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
    .then((data) => {
     this.setState({ users: data })
     console.log(this.info.users)
   })
  }
  info = {
   users: []
  } 
  render() {
   return (
    <React.Fragment>
    <h1>All Users</h1>
    <table border='1' width='100%'>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Fullname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
    </tr>

    {this.info.users.map((user) => (
      <tr>
        <td>{ user.username }</td>
        <td>{ user.fullname }</td>
        <td>{ user.email }</td>
      </tr>
    ))}
    </table>
    </React.Fragment>
   );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>
```

The json that is being returned from the testQuery.php script looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "uid":"7",
    "username":"tna.mjordan",
    "fullname":"Michael Jordan",
    "email":"tna.mjordan@tna.com",
    "userlevel":"9",
    "division":"Chicago"
  }, 
  // and so on
]
```

Any thoughts as to why I am getting a blank users array, and how to fix it?

Comment: Your console.log statement is this.info.users. Where is that being set? Your setState just sets users to data, but data doesn't have an "info" field. Basically, you're setting this.users, but then reading this.info.users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to print the info from the state, not the attribute itself. Same happens in the returned renderized HTML. Besides, the setState should modify the `info` attribute, not the `users` property within. Below you can find your code with the changes applied:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const url = "api/testQuery.php";
    axios
      .get(url)
      .then((response) => data)
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({ info: { users: data } });
        console.log(this.state.info.users);
      });
  }
  info = {
    users: [],
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>All Users</h1>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
          <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Fullname</th>
            <th>Email</th>
          </tr>

          {this.state.info.users.map((user) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{user.username}</td>
              <td>{user.fullname}</td>
              <td>{user.email}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </table>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: The word "info" was the problem.  Replacing "info" with "state" fixed it.  Thanks you so much for your help.